# Understanding GRNN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Hi I have a fingerprint recognition system which I am adding a GRNN into, my problem being is that the GRNN was already half implemented when it was given to me to improve on and I've never used Matlab before. I feel like I've been thrown in the deep end in a program I don't know, and there is very very little help with how GRNNs work, how to implement one and how to understand the output. Here is the GRNN code that was already added, it does give an output however with my little Matlab knowledge, interpreting the output is tricky. Any and all help is welcome.

```
function btrain(P,T)

P = dlmread('featresToTrain.txt'); %features matrix 57x198
T = dlmread('target2.txt'); %these are the targets 50x1 but that should have been 57x1
%P = P(:,149);

P = P(1:51,1:21);
[r c] = size(P);
for i = 1:r
    s = sum(P(i,:));
    P(i,c+1) = s;
end

 %so 50 are used here P(rows 1 to 50,columns 1 to 20) 
%net = newff(P',T',[8 1],{'tansig','purelin'});

 tic;
 net = newgrnn(P',T');
AA = net(P')
 toc
for i=1:r
test = P(i,:);
out = sim(net,test');
out,i;
end
figure,
plot(P,T)

% net = init(net);
% net.trainParam.epochs= 1000;
% net.trainParam.min_grad = 1e-9;
% net.trainParam.goal = 0.000001;
% net.performParam.ratio=0.5;
% 
% [net,tr] = train(net,P',T');
% x = net.IW;
% inputWeights = x{1};
% dlmwrite('inputWeights.txt',inputWeights);
% x = net.LW;
% layerWeights = x{2,1};
% dlmwrite('layerWeights.txt',layerWeights);
% x = net.b;
% baises = x{1};
% dlmwrite('baises.txt',baises);

test = dlmread('featresToTest.txt'); %[22 45 124 111 160 222 301 183 252 224 270 151 291 272 267 214 286 142 41 181];

round(out)
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: It may help if you add the output and explain what you understand/don't understand about it. Otherwise, without the input data (in featresToTrain.txt and target2.txt), it is not possible for anyone else to run the code and see what you are seeing.

Comment: out = 1 out = 1 out = 1 out = 1 out = 1 out = 2 out = 2
it carries on like that until out = 11. I figure it has something to do with how well the GRNN is working? But honestly to me it looks like a list of numbers :/

Comment: OK, that's just `round(out)` displaying because no `;` on the end of that line. I don't know GRNN library in Matlab, but looking through the script, I do feel you may be better off starting from something different to the inherited code e.g. https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/nnet/nndemos/demogrn1.m

Comment: This is just an example program to play around with a bit? I'm finding it quite helpful for changing bits of code and seeing what is does. It's going to take a while to figure out but thanks for the pointer!